# Is a NativeScript app what the user sees on a mobile device or what he downloads from the app store?

Tags: angular, typescript, nativescript, nativescript-angular

I'm a newbie to Angular and just learning Angular apps with TypeScript with a C# ASP.Net Core Web Api app as the server side project.

Question - if I build up a NativeScript app along side the Angular TypeScript app, is that what the user sees on the screen when using a mobile device (iPad, iPhone, etc.) or is that what I upload to the app store and downloaded, by a user, to the mobile device to run as a native app?

And if it's the first, how does the device know which one to use to look at, being that I can build the TypeScript app with bootstrap and accommodate the code for mobile devices?

Answer (score 2):

Play store/ App Store is a centralised repository from where users can download your app. I think you are getting mixed up between [PWA](https://developers.google.com/web/progressive-web-apps/) and native apps.  Nativescript is used to created Native mobile apps that you can debug/run/build directly to any ios/android device. 
You can publish it either Apple or Google store to make it available for public however there are certain steps involved for that.

But Short answer to your question is *Yes*, app will be same when you build and deploy directly to device or publish it to store and download afterwards.

P.S. Angular is just a framework you use, you can also choose either vue.js or vanilla Javascript to develop apps in NativeScript. And it does not matter if you have C# ASP.Net Core Web Api or Java as backend.

EDIT: The objective for code sharing project is to share as much code as possible, and split the platform-specific code into separate files.

This usually means that we can share the code for:

Routes for navigation,
Services for common business logic,
and Component Class definition for common behaviour of a component

Comment: Let me make sure I understand your response. Creating a NativeScript application is only used to publish my application to the store for people to download and use? So my Angular app is what people see on the web, regardless of the device (phone, tablet, laptop, etc) and my NativeScript app is what they see when they download my app from the store?

Comment: yes, you are almost there. But with code sharing ability of Nativescript allows you to build web app and mobile app from the same code basd. https://docs.nativescript.org/code-sharing/intro

Comment: ok, say I want to build a dating/match website. The web/desktop/laptop interface is going to look a lot different then the mobile app. So, should I build the web app in Angular and the mobile app in NativeScript? Or is there a better option?

Comment: Yes, you can choose different look and feel for web and native app.Nativescript is still a better option. The objective for code sharing project is to share as much code as possible, and split the platform-specific code into separate files.

This usually means that we can share the code for:

Routes for navigation,
Services for common business logic,
and Component Class definition for common behaviour of a component